# need to join table on based of condition in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, outer-join

I want to integrate like functionality in iOS/android app.
I am developing service for that.
My question is :
I have table called songs in which I have song details

```
**like**

song
song_id
station_id
song_file
```

so on.
I have second table called userlike where user like inforamation are stored.

```
**userlike**
user_id
song_id
like
```

My main problem is that I want to return all song details with like value information for particular user.If uer has not like it then I may send 'zero' or null in my JSON.
How to build this query?
I  need song data and like value if user has liked it.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @TheEwook Read this: [“What have you tried” epidemic](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172758/what-have-you-tried-epidemic)

Comment: what is the column `like` in `userlike`?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select s.song, s.song_id from song s , userlike u where u.user_id = your userId;
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming `userlike.like` is `boolean` value

```
SELECT like.song, like.song_id,
 like.station_id,
 like.song_file,
IFNULL(userlike.like,0)
from like left join userlike on like.song_id=userlike.song_id
and userlike.user_id=/*your userid*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use an `OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT s.song_id, s.song, u.like
FROM song s 
    LEFT JOIN userlike u 
        ON s.song_id = u.song_id 
            AND u.user_id = @userId
```

Putting the userId in the Join will ensure the song is returned even if the user hasn't liked it.

Answer (score 0):

```
select songs.song_id as song_id , songs.station_id as station_id , songs.song_file as song_file , userlike.user_id as user_id ,  COALESCE(userlike.like, 0) as like 
            FROM songs LEFT JOIN userlike
            on songs.song_id = userlike.song_id
            and userlike.user_id = 'your particular user'
```

The above sql should work. Please look for table name and column names for correction.

Thanks